# Can the "guest" user login via RDP in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

Does remote desktop permit the guest user to log in? If so, how do I add the guest user the remote desktop ACL? I've added a password for guest using `net user guest *`, I just want to permit remote desktop logins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the [answer here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758036(WS.10).aspx)

**To add users to the Remote Desktop Users group**

1. Open Computer Management.
2. In the console tree, click the Local Users and Groups node.
3. In the details pane, double-click the Groups folder.
4. Double-click Remote Desktop Users, and then click Add....
5. On the Select Users dialog box, click Locations... to specify the search location.
6. Click Object Types... to specify the types of objects you want to search for.
7. Type the name you want to add in the Enter the object names to select (examples): box.
8. Click Check Names.
9. When the name is located, click OK.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Add Guest to the Remote Desktop Users group.

Here's a [guide with pictures](http://www.helpwithwindows.com/WindowsXP/howto-14.html).